# Why is my GetKeyUp not being detected in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically i am trying to move a character around so when i press W it goes forward but when i let go it doesn't stop(only once in a while). I am on Update void and not fixed Update.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetInteger("condition", 1);
            moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            moveDir *= speed;
            moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetInteger("condition", 0);
            moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    rot += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rot, 0);

    moveDir.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move (moveDir * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

Comment: Possibly because of your check for `controller.isGrounded`.  When you `GetKey` (which should be `GetKeyDown` since you are using Up) you are changing your y position and therefore when Update( ) comes back around you are no longer grounded.  Try it out, also replace `GetKey` with `GetKeyUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at your animator and checking that Apply Root Motion is checked off.
[Animator in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxmxc.png)

What root motion does is that it moves your character through the animation instead of through code. Here is a detailed explanation on root motion. [What's root motion and how it works](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1238987/whats-root-motion-and-how-it-works.html)

I think I was able to recreate your issue and I was getting the same results. After I unchecked Apply Root Motion, my character stopped once I let go of "W".